# Is there a way to delete canvas objects separately(one by one) fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I have add multiple objects(images) to the canvas and i only need to delete some selected object with a button click.Is there a way to do that. And also i need maintain a separate id for each objects which are added to the canvas. Is there a way to do this in fabric js. 
PS: I want to maintain a list. in that list i want to added object details which are inserted to the canvas.

```js
function initCanvas() {
  $('.canvas-container').each(function(index) {

    var canvasContainer = $(this)[0];
    var canvasObject = $("canvas", this)[0];

    var imageOffsetX, imageOffsetY;

    function handleDragStart(e) {
      [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
      });
      this.classList.add('img_dragging');
      var imageOffset = $(this).offset();
      imageOffsetX = e.clientX - imageOffset.left;
      imageOffsetY = e.clientY - imageOffset.top;
    }

    function handleDragOver(e) {
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
      return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnter(e) {
      this.classList.add('over');
    }

    function handleDragLeave(e) {
      this.classList.remove('over');
    }

    function handleDrop(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      var img = document.querySelector('.furniture img.img_dragging');
      //console.log('event: ', e);

      var offset = $(canvasObject).offset();
      var y = e.clientY - (offset.top + imageOffsetY);
      var x = e.clientX - (offset.left + imageOffsetX);

      var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        id: img.id
      });
      canvas.add(newImage);
      return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnd(e) {
      [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
      });
    }

    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.furniture img');
    [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
      img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
      img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  });
}
initCanvas();

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
  selection: false
});

function deleteobject(){
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
 
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="canvas1" style="border: 1px solid;width: 500px;height: 500px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="furniture" style="padding: 20px;border: 1px solid;width: 460px">
      <h3>Drag the image to canvas</h3> 
      <img id="pic1" draggable="true" src="https://www.mve.com/media/Move_logo_-01.png" width="60">
      <img id="pic2" draggable="true" src="https://young.scot/media/8787/second-chances-logo-802x644.png" width="60">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="deleteobject()">Delete</button>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: You can get the doc from [here](http://fabricjs.com/docs/).

Comment: Thank you @Durga You always been really helpful. (Y)

Comment: @durga I have read the doc but i couldn't find a way to get a unique id for added object to the canvas. Is there a way to do that.

Comment: There is no unique id for canvas object, you can create for your own. while creating object set your id.

Comment: Can you give me some more details (sample project or post link)  about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [canvas.remove(selectedObject)](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#remove) to remove an object.

***DEMO***

```js
function initCanvas() {
  $('.canvas-container').each(function(index) {

    var canvasContainer = $(this)[0];
    var canvasObject = $("canvas", this)[0];

    var imageOffsetX, imageOffsetY;

    function handleDragStart(e) {
      [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
      });
      this.classList.add('img_dragging');
      var imageOffset = $(this).offset();
      imageOffsetX = e.clientX - imageOffset.left;
      imageOffsetY = e.clientY - imageOffset.top;
    }

    function handleDragOver(e) {
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
      return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnter(e) {
      this.classList.add('over');
    }

    function handleDragLeave(e) {
      this.classList.remove('over');
    }

    function handleDrop(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      var img = document.querySelector('.furniture img.img_dragging');
      //console.log('event: ', e);

      var offset = $(canvasObject).offset();
      var y = e.clientY - (offset.top + imageOffsetY);
      var x = e.clientX - (offset.left + imageOffsetX);

      var newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
        width: img.width,
        height: img.height,
        left: x,
        top: y,
        id: img.id
      });
      canvas.add(newImage);
      return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnd(e) {
      [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
        img.classList.remove('img_dragging');
      });
    }

    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.furniture img');
    [].forEach.call(images, function(img) {
      img.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
      img.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasContainer.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
  });
}
initCanvas();

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1', {
  selection: false
});

function deleteobject(){
  var selectedObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  selectedObject && canvas.remove(selectedObject);
  
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
 
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="canvas1" style="border: 1px solid;width: 500px;height: 500px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="furniture" style="padding: 20px;border: 1px solid;width: 460px">
      <h3>Drag the image to canvas</h3> 
      <img id="pic1" draggable="true" src="https://www.mve.com/media/Move_logo_-01.png" width="60">
      <img id="pic2" draggable="true" src="https://young.scot/media/8787/second-chances-logo-802x644.png" width="60">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="deleteobject()">Delete</button>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.min.js'></script>
```